# Google Cloud Platform: API Latency and Errors

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I have an application that uses Google Sheets API service to read/write values to a particular Google Sheet. This application has been working fine for years, just today it suddenly started facing API errors (504 Gateway Timeout) thrown by Google Sheets API.

Upon investigation I noticed on the Google Cloud Platform that the performance charts are showing 100% errors faced by the Google Sheet v4 API, especially the API for reading values.
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the Google Cloud Platform charts above (which is somehow showing a 503 error instead of 504 received by my application), the Errors by API Method chart is repeatedly showing 100% errors on today's date. At times its working but most of the time the API is throwing error.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this problem. Are the API Errors shown by Google Cloud Platform are their internal server errors which Google fill fix itself, or is it something that I need to change on my side? I have not changed the code recently so its not likely that my application may be causing API errors. Appreciate guidance on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: As a test, when a new Spreadsheet is created and you test your current script with the new Spreadsheet, what result will you obtain? And also,  how many cells are used in your current Spreadsheet? I'm worried that the size of the Spreadsheet might be related to your current issue. But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, if those were not related to your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: My current spreadsheet has become huge over the years and currently my application is using a particular spreadsheet, kind of like a database for storing its data on it, in the absence of a real relational database. However, I am well below the quota limits set by Google Cloud Platform. Could the large size of data transmission be giving a 504 Gateway Timeout? Or should that be some other HTTP error code?

Comment: You are overloading the Spreadsheet API. `server-side error that indicates that the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or maintenance` Implement [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) and retry requests.

Comment: Thanks, I have already implemented the exponential backoff which didn't help. I suppose I am overloading the API with large data transmission. I will have to break it into several smaller API calls and data chunks by separating spreadsheets. Thanks for the info.